# ReactJS / Javascript How to remove the duplicate array of objects from multi dimentional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js, javascript-objects

```
const array = [
  {id: 1029, name: 'College-Annual-Day.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153, …},
  {id: 1029, name: 'College-Annual-Day.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153, …}
];
```

Comment: Do you want to find the duplicated based only on ID or do you want to check for all the keys?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the duplicate objects by checking for all the keys:

You have `_.uniq` function of [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)

```js
const sourceArray = [ {id: 1029, name: 'College-Annual-Day.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153}, {id: 1029, name: 'College-Annual-Day.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153} ]
const destArray = _.uniq(sourceArray, function(x){
    return x.name;
});
console.log(destArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.3/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

If you want in plain Javascript

```js
var uniqueProperties = {};

var array = [ {id: 1029, name: 'College-Annual-Day.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153}, {id: 1029, name: 'College-Annual-Day.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153} ]


for(var object in array){
   uniqueProperties[array[object]['name']] = array[object]['id'];
}

var uniqiueArray = [];

for(var uniqueName in uniqueProperties){
   uniqiueArray.push(
     { id: uniqueProperties[uniqueName], name:uniqueName });
}

console.log(uniqiueArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered before in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

```js
let array = [
  {id: 1029, name: 'College-Annual-Day.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153},
  {id: 1029, name: 'College-Annual-Day.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153},
  {id: 1029, name: 'College-Annual-Day.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153},
  {id: 1029, name: 'College-Annual-Day.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153},
  {id: 1030, name: 'College-Annual-Day-2.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153},
  {id: 1031, name: 'College-Annual-Day-3.jpg', ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', size: 91153}
];
array = array.filter((value, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => t.id === value.id
 )
)

console.log(array)
```